# How to add a search bar functionality to all the templates of django?

Tags: django

I am trying to add a search bar in my django site. I added a form in my base template. I have added the functionality to my home view. It is working in the home view. But not in other views. I tried creating a new view but i.e. Is not working too. Please tell me what should I do?

views.py:

```py
def search(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        query = request.GET.get('q').split()
        if query:
            queryset =  reduce(
                operator.__or__,
                [
                    Q(title__icontains=queries) | Q(content__icontains=queries)
                    for queries in query
                ]
            )
            posts = Post.objects.filter(queryset).distinct()

            return render(request, "blog/home.html", {'posts': posts})
```

template:-

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" action="{% url 'blog-home' %}" method="GET" type="search" placeholder="Search Posts" aria-label="Search" name="q">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve/', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove/', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/delete/', views.comment_delete, name='comment_delete'),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('feedback/', views.contact_us, name='contact_us'),
    path('search/', views.search),
]
```

Comment: please provide some code and more details

Comment: Welcome. You need to provide some code so people can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I performed my search function. First we get the object of the model we want and then we get the q which is the name of the input in my template and than filter as per the field that we want. The form action that I mention before is the solution for your problem.

view.py

```
def course_view(request):
latest_course = Course.objects.all()
query = request.GET.get('q')
print(query)
if query:
    latest_course = Course.objects.filter(
        Q(title__icontains=query)|
        Q(user__full_name=query)|
        Q(price__icontains=query)
    )
context = {
    'latest_course': latest_course,
}

return render(request, 'apps/course.html', context)
```

template.html( Its in my base template like yours)

```
      <div class="sidebar-search">
            <form method="GET" action="{% url 'courses' %}">
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control search-menu" placeholder="Search..." name='q'>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your template form tag add the URL name where you want to load the search function. This way you can search from any page and will redirect you that page. If you don't get it I can provide you with a reference code so that you can grasp some idea.

```
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'courses' %}">
```

Comment: Please give the reference code. Because I tried a lot of things but it didn't work out.

Comment: could you be more detail and specific with the errors

Comment: There is no error while running the website. But it is not functioning.I created a new view (search) in which I am trying to get the post related to the query passed by search bar in by navbar which is located in my base template. If you see the above code I am rendering my home template with the search results of the query passed by the user. Right now, when I type query into search bar anything is happening.